# Why does with(data, summarySE(...)) return 'non-numeric argument to mathematical function' error?

Tags: r

If I understand `with()` correctly, the following should produce identical results:

```
> myFunction(data, ...)
> with(data, myFunction(...))
```

For example, the following produce identical plots.

```
> plot(data=mtcars, mpg ~ disp)
> with(mtcars, plot(mpg ~ disp))
```

However, I'm having trouble understanding the following.

```
> library(Rmisc)   # provides summarySE() and summarySEWithin()
> summarySE(data=subset(mtcars, gear==4), measurevar="hp",
+           groupvars=c("am", "carb"))
  am carb N    hp       sd        se        ci
1  0    2 2  78.5 23.33452 16.500000 209.65238
2  0    4 2 123.0  0.00000  0.000000   0.00000
3  1    1 4  72.5 13.67479  6.837397  21.75965
4  1    2 2  80.5 40.30509 28.500000 362.12683
5  1    4 2 110.0  0.00000  0.000000   0.00000
> with(subset(mtcars, gear==4), {
+   summarySE(measurevar="hp", groupvars=c("am", "carb"))
+ })
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: mean
Error in sqrt(datac$N) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Why is the output of `summarySE()` fine when the data argument is provided directly, but not when provided through `with()`?

It seems the problem is arising at Line 44 of summarySE():

```
datac$se <- datac$sd / sqrt(datac$N)  # Calculate standard error of the mean
```

(from https://github.com/RyanHope/Rmisc/blob/master/R/summarySE.R)

I'm guessing that `summarySE()` is being executed without getting the `data` argument (and hence defaulting to null), so ultimately `sqrt()` is getting `NA` as its argument. Assuming this is correct, how can I make sure `summarySE()` gets the `data` argument from `with()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason that `myFunction(data, ...)` and `with(data, myFunction(...))` should be the same. `data` is not a reserved name for an argument (nor is the first positional arg reserved), and can actually be anything.
(*edit:* added side notes at the end (*))

That being said, it is indeed a very common pattern that `data` is expected to be a data frame, and that its elements are made available through standard or non standard evaluation in the other arguments of the function call.
Even then, some functions allow those "other arguments" to be fetched either in the calling environment or in `data`, like `plot()` in your example, some others don't... like `summarySE()` that mandates that `measurevar` and `groupvars` be found in `data`, not in the calling environment.

So I see no simple way to "make sure `summarySE()` gets the data argument from `with()`". Or I can think of one, but it's kind of absurd, and completely defeats the purpose of using `with()`:

```
(function(data)
  with(data, summarySE(data, measurevar="hp", groupvars=c("am", "carb")))
)(subset(mtcars, gear==4))
```

---

((*) Side notes:

(what `with()` does is simply to make available the elements of `data` when evaluating `expr`. Its source code is only one line! `eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())`)

(by the way, the behavior you describe resembles more that of the `magrittr` pipe: `myFunction(data, ...)` and `` `%>%`(data, myFunction(...)) `` are more or less equivalent (or, more commonly: `data %>% myFunction(...)`).

Comment: Thanks, @Aurèle, for the lucid answer and explanation. Apparently, I assumed too much about what `with()` is for. I have much yet to learn about R...